# Single tape TM that converts numbers from binary notation to unary

Tags: turing-machines, time-complexity

I need to construct a TM that converts a number from binary notation to unary and calculate time complexity.

I have done the first part.

The idea is as follows:

> binary number is decremented by 1 until it reaches 0. At each
> decrement an additional 1 is written on the left side.

e.g.

> 111 -> 1111111
> 111x (TM goes to the end of the binary number and writes x)
> 110x1
> 101x11
> 100x111
> 011x1111
> 010x11111
> 001x111111
> 000x1111111
> 1111111 (TM removes zeros and x; end)

And now comes the time complexity part. So far I have:
(1) TM will do $n$ (length of the binary number) steps to reach the end of the input word, additional  1 for writing x and 1 for moving back, so $n+2$;
(2) there are $2^{n}-1$ decrements, at that time TM will take in total $2 \times \frac{(2^{n}-1) (2^{n})}{2}$ steps on the left side, plus $2\times (2^{n}-1)$ for the x's. (no idea how many on the right side).
(3) TM will take $2n+1$ steps for removing unnecessary zeros and x at the end.

I don't know how to put this all together, plus some missing information in (2). Can anyone tell me if I'm computing correctly and how to proceed.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It is a bit confusing as to what $n$ corresponds to. Be clear if it is the **value** of the entry or its **size**.

Comment: @Nathaniel, its size (length)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have said, there are $2^n-1$ total "decrements". Notice that at the $k$'th decrement, you "waste" $O(n)$ time on the left side, plus $O(k)$ at the right side. Sum everything up, from $k=1$ up to $k=2^n-1$:

$\sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1} n+k = n(2^n-1)+\sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1} k = n(2^n-1) + O(2^{2n})=O(2^{2n})$

Answer (score 1):

put this code into https://turingmachine.io/

```
name: Binary to Decimal
source code: |
  input: '100#'
  blank: ' '
  B : ' '
  start state : Right
  table:
    Right : 
      [0,1] : R
      '#' : {L : q0}
    q0:
      0 : {write : 1, L}
      1 : {write : 0, R : q1}
      ' ' : {R : clear}
    q1:
      [0,1] : R
      '#' : {R : q2}
    q2 :
      ' ' : {write : 1, L : q3}
      1 : R
      '#' : {L : q3}
    q3:
      1 : L
      '#' : {L : q0}
    clear : 
      1 : {write : ' ', R}
positions:
  Right: {x: 123.15, y: 317.95}
  q0: {x: 158.84, y: 165.35}
  q1: {x: 339.94, y: 121.45}
  q2: {x: 477.32, y: 257.12}
  q3: {x: 353.45, y: 344.81}
  clear: {x: 34.35, y: 168.07}
```